# How to run hive on google cloud dataproc from within the machine?

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I've just created a google cloud dataproc cluster. A few basic things are not working for me:

1. I'm trying to run the hive console from the master node but it fails to load with any user other than root (it looks like there's a lock, the console is just stuck).
2. But even when using root, I see some odd behaviour:

   - "show tables;" shows a table named "input"
   - querying the table raises an exception that this table not found.
3. It is not clear which user is creating the tables through the web ui. I create a job, execute it, but then don't see the results through the console.

Couldn't find any good documentation on that - does anybody have an idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the `hive` command at present is somewhat broken due to the default metastore configuration.

I recommend you use the [beeline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93NewCommandLineShell) client instead, which talks to the same Hive Server 2 as Dataproc Hive Jobs. You can use it via ssh by running `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000` on the master.

YARN applications are submitted by the Hive Server 2 as the user "nobody", you can specify a different user by passing the `-n` flag to beeline, but it shouldn't matter with default permissions.

Answer (score 0):

*This thread is a bit old but when some one search Google Cloud Platform and Hive this result is coming. So I'm adding some info which may be useful.*

Currently, in order to submit job to Google dataproc, I think - like all other products - there are 3 options:

1. from UI
2. from console using command line like:
   `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=CLUSTER (--execute=QUERY, -e QUERY     | --file=FILE, -f FILE) [--async] [--bucket=BUCKET] [--continue-on-failure] [--jars=[JAR,…]] [--labels=[KEY=VALUE,…]] [--params=[PARAM=VALUE,…]] [--properties=[PROPERTY=VALUE,…]] [GLOBAL-FLAG …]`
3. REST API call like: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/submit

Hope this will be useful to someone.